# Will i3 9100F support my ECC unbuffered RAM?

Tags: memory, cpu, ecc, intel-core-i3

I read from the intel website that i3 9100f supports ECC ram, and when I am buying the ECC RAM, the guy said that the i3 9100F won't run with unbuffered RAM.

Can anyone confirm this?
My motherboard is Gigabyte C246M-WU4 which support ECC unbuffered and i3 9100F

Thanks

Comment: The processor does indeed support ECC memory.